# differences of usage with conjunctive adverb

Tags: british-english, adverbs, writing-style

> a) You must have a good reason for possession of a bladed instrument.
> It will have to be genuine, **for example**, someone back packing may
> use one for the preparation of meals.
>
> b) You can put knives in your bin. **However** it is still advisable
> to package the knifes securely.

How does the usage in these examples differ from using a conjunctive adverb with a semi-colon? Are we not just using for example as the word 'like' in example  a)

What types of sentence require a semi-colon with the conjunctive adverb versus beginning the sentence with However?

Comment: What do you mean by "Are we not just using for example as the word 'like'"?

Comment: No sentences **require** a semi-colon with the conjunctive adverb. Ending the sentence and beginning the next one with "however" is often a good resolution. I'd shorten: "You must have a good reason for possessing a blade, like backpacking."

Comment: Yes, "for example" and "like" mean the same thing in this context.

Comment: (1) At least a semicolon (optionally a new sentence) is needed after 'genuine'. (2) Most would consider a comma after 'However' mandatory here.

Comment: alphabet    (genuine, like someone back packing)...  As written the writer is not treating for example as a 'conjunction' rather just a less formal contrast which is wrong. My question overall is asking what the distinction is with a conjunction for instance: However versus any other use of however.  He didn't like football. However, he was good at golf. She hated people; however, she had an affinity towards animals.